# Protocol Extension in Swift Where Object Is a Class and conforms to a Protocol

Tags: swift

I have two protocols (`Archivable` and `Serializable`) and a class (`Model`) that is subclassed multiple times. Many of the subclasses implement either `Archivable` or `Serializable` (or both). I'd like to define a function on all children of `Model` that implement both `Archivable` and `Serializable`. Both of these work:

```
extension Serializable where Self: Model {
  func fetch() { ... }
}
```

**or**

```
extension Serializable where Self: Archivable {
  func fetch() { ... }
}
```

However I can't figure out how to extend where both protocols are required. Are there any other options outside of creating a third protocol that conforms to the first two?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
extension Archivable where Self: Model, Self: Serializable {

    func fetch() { ... }

}
```

... or the other way around:

```
extension Serializable where Self: Model, Self: Archivable {

    func fetch() { ... }

}
```

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I needed. Will mark as answer once the system lets me.

Comment: it's a great tip!

Answer (score 6):

You can use a composition of protocols

```
extension Serializable where Self: Model & Archivable {
    func fetch() { ... }
}
```